# How to make Telegram bot inline keyboard private? Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

```js
// command for starting request with a simple anti-spam shiet
bot.command('movie', (ctx) => {   
        let stopSpam = findUserData(ctx);
        if (stopSpam) {
            ctx.reply(spammerMsg)
        } else {
            userData.push({id: ctx.message.from.id, msgId: ctx.message.message_id});
            ctx.reply('Género',genreMenu);
        } 
});

// So the issue is right here. 
//Right now I'm checking if the user has already used the comand 'movie'. 
//If so, he could use its buttons. But he could use the buttons from another user too...
bot.action(/.+/,(ctx) => {
    let allowed = findUserCallbackData(ctx);
    if (allowed) {
        ctx.editMessageReplyMarkup((m) => m.inlineKeyboard([]));
        allowed.queryGenre = ctx.update.callback_query.data;
        ctx.reply('Época', timeMenu)
            .then(() => {
                ctx.deleteMessage(ctx.update.callback_query.message.message_id)
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e)
            })
    }   else {
        console.log('noppe')
    }
});

findUserData = (ctx) => {
    let findCmdUser = userData.find(user => user.id === ctx.message.from.id)
    return findCmdUser
}

findUserCallbackData = (ctx) => {
    let findUser = userData.find(user => user.id === ctx.update.callback_query.from.id)
    return findUser
}
```

I'm in a cinema telegram group and I'm making a bot for movies recomendations using **inline keyboard** as data giver.

The issue is inline keyboard **is not only visible but interactive for every single group member**.

So my question is, can I prevent this from happening somehow? Can I make the inline keyboard only accesible (and visible, if possible) for the user which inserts the proper command?

Sorry for my basic English and thank's for your time.

Comment: probably but you would need to submit a jsfiddle or some sort of code.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to edit right now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inline keyboard is attached directly to message so it's not possible to make it visible for some participants only.